# Prove that for all $x$, $\sum_{j=0}^{n}ℓ_j(x)=1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, interpolation

**Prove that for all $x$, $\sum_{j=0}^{n}ℓ_j(x)=1$**

$ℓ_j(x)$ are obtained by means of Lagrange interpolation and are defined as $ℓ_j(x)=\prod_{i=0, i\neq j}^{n}\frac{x-x_i}{x_j-x_i}$ where 
$x_i, i=0,1,...,n$ are the nodes given to interpolate, with which I have to prove that $\sum_{j=0}^{n}\prod_{i=0, i\neq j}^{n}\frac{x-x_i}{x_j-x_i}=1$ but I do not know how to do this, could someone help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Think about what happens what you plug in $x = x_i$...

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the polynomial
$$
Q(x) \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \sum_{j=0}^n \ell_j(x) -1\,.
$$
which is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ as every $\ell_j$ is.

It is easy to check that, for any $j$ and $i$, $$\ell_j(x_i) = \begin{cases} 0&\text{ if } i\neq j\\ 
1&\text{ if } i=j
\end{cases}$$
and therefore, we have, for every $0\leq i\leq n$,
$$
Q(x_i) = \sum_{j=0}^n \ell_j(x_i) - 1 = \ell_i(x_i) - 1 = 1-1=0
$$ 
and since $Q$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ with $n+1$ roots, it has to be identically zero.

Answer (score 2):

$ \sum_{j=0}^{n}\ell_j(x)= \sum_{j=0}^{n} 1 \ell_j(x)$ is the expression of Lagrange interpolation for the constant function $1$.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I suspect the OP's question is a step to prove the correctness of Lagrange interpolation. (if that's correct, then your answer is circular.)

Comment: @ClementC., you may be right. Let's hope the OP clarifies. Thanks.