# Prove that a collection of certain polynomials sum to unity

Tags: polynomials, summation, projection, projection-matrices

Consider a (finite) collection of $n$ distinct constants $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ and define the polynomial in $x$
$$P_i(x):=\prod_{j\in\{1,\dots,n\}}^{j\neq i}\frac{(x-f_j)}{(f_i-f_j)}~,$$
for $1\leq i \leq n$. I wish to prove the property that the sum of all such polynomials is unity,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}P_i(x)=1~.$$
The brute force method of finding a common denominator and naively summing doesn't seem to be very practical, so how should I approach this?

Note that this problem actually appears within the context of orthogonal projectors. In particular, the $P_i(x)$ is really a projector to the eigenspace $V_i$ associated with an eigenvalue $f_i$ of an operator $x$ defined to act on some $n$ dimensional vector space $V$. However, I believe this property should hold regardless of this context, and I do not want to use this information in the proof.

Comment: Hunt for information about Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: Another group of keywords : "partition of unity".

Comment: Thanks for the keywords, I wasn't aware of Lagrange interpolation. I've linked a thread below which provides a nice answer to my question.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759584/prove-that-for-all-x-sum-j-0n%e2%84%93-jx-1?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Have you any idea how I might prove the result if $x$ were treated as a linear operator acting on an $n$ dimensional space instead? All the proofs use some property like e.g. the fundamental theorem of algebra, which is valid in this case. (By the way, this is not a complaint, as I asked for a proof assuming it was a polynomial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomials $P_i(x)$ are called the Lagrange polynomials associated to the nodes $f_i$. They are commonly used to compute interpolating polynomials. In particular, since $P_i(f_j) = \delta_{ij}$, the interpolating polynomial of some function $g(x)$ in the nodes $f_1, \cdots, f_n$ is given by
$$
p(x)= \sum_{i=1}^n g(f_i) P_i(x).
$$

If you consider the constant function $g(x) = 1$, the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the cleanest way to do it, but it is functional. Define $T(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n P_i(x)$, now using log-derivation, find $T'(x)$, and you can first check some small cases, I mean, $n=2,3$, so you can see that $T'(x)=0$. Then, the function $T(x)$ is constant. It is not difficult to show that $T(0)=1$. Then, $T(x)=1$.

Comment: You mention that I should check that T'(x)=0 for small $n$, and then convince myself that it's true in general. To me, this is just as convincing (and just as computationally expensive) as just showing that the original result holds for small $n$ cases, and hence should hold in general. It also isn't really a proof, just an argument. Can you convince me otherwise?

Comment: It was only for given to you some starting point. Log-derivation should be used in the general case to manage the products and sums. So, the derivative of $T$ will be zero expressions on the denominator of the type $f_i-f_j$ and also $f_j-f_i$ appears. But, of course, the smallest case is only to see the patron, the general proof in using this method was provided by another answer that at the moment is erased.